# What is _md5.md5 and why is hashlib.md5 so much slower?

Tags: python, performance, md5, checksum, hashlib

Found this undocumented `_md5` when getting frustrated with the slow stdlib `hashlib.md5` implementation.

On a macbook:

```
>>> timeit hashlib.md5(b"hello world")
597 ns ± 17.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
>>> timeit _md5.md5(b"hello world")
224 ns ± 3.18 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
>>> _md5
<module '_md5' from '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_md5.cpython-37m-darwin.so'>
```

On a Windows box:

```
>>> timeit hashlib.md5(b"stonk overflow")
328 ns ± 21.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
>>> timeit _md5.md5(b"stonk overflow")
110 ns ± 12.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
>>> _md5
<module '_md5' (built-in)>
```

On a Linux box:

```
>>> timeit hashlib.md5(b"https://adventofcode.com/2016/day/5")
259 ns ± 1.33 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
>>> timeit _md5.md5(b"https://adventofcode.com/2016/day/5")
102 ns ± 0.0576 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
>>> _md5
<module '_md5' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_md5.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'>
```

For hashing short messages, it's way faster. For long messages, similar performance.

Why is it hidden away in an underscore extension module, and why isn't this faster implementation used by default in hashlib?  **What is the `_md5` module** and why doesn't it have public API?

Comment: What sort of relative performance do you get on longer strings (e.g. 5 megabytes long)?

Comment: Interesting - with 5 MB of urandom, the performance seems similar (within margin of error).  But for mining [AdventCoin](https://adventofcode.com/2016/day/5) I needed to hash short messages..

Comment: My guess is that the results of the small-string tests are being dominated by the overhead of setting up the call, rather than by the algorithm itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Until *Python 2.**5***, hashes and digests were implemented in their own modules (e.g. [[Python 2.Docs]: md5 - MD5 message digest algorithm](https://docs.python.org/2/library/md5.html)).
Starting with *v2.5*, [[Python 2.6.Docs]: hashlib - Secure hashes and message digests](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/hashlib.html) was added. Its purpose was to:

1. Offer an unified access method to the hashes / digests (via their name)
2. Switch (**by default**) to an external cryptography provider (it seems the logical step to delegate to some entity specialized in that field, as maintaining all those algorithms could be an overkill). At that time *OpenSSL* was the best choice: mature enough, known and compatible (there were a bunch of similar *Java* providers, but those were pretty useless)

As a side effect of ***#2.***, the *Python* implementations were hidden from the public *API* (renamed them: *_md5*, *_sha1*, *_sha256*, *_sha512*, and the latter ones added: *_blake2*, *_sha3*), as redundancy often creates confusions.
**But, another side effect was *_hashlib.so* dependency on *OpenSSL*'s *libcrypto*.so*** (this is *Nix* (at least *Linux*) specific, on *Win*, a static *libeay32.lib* was linked in *_hashlib.pyd*, and also *_ssl.pyd* (which I consider lame), till *v3.**7**+*, where *OpenSSL* *.dll*s are part of the *Python* installation).
Probably on *90%+* of the machines things were smooth, as *OpenSSL* was / is installed by default, but for those where it isn't, many things might get broken because for example *hashlib* is imported by many modules (one such example is *random* which itself gets imported by lots of others), so **trivial pieces of code that are not related at all to cryptography (at least not at 1<sup>st</sup> sight) will stop working**. That's why the old implementations are kept (but again, they are only fallbacks as *OpenSSL* versions are / should be better maintained).

> ```bash
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q059955854]> ~/sopr.sh
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [064bit-prompt]> python3 -c "import sys, hashlib as hl, _md5, ssl;print(\"{0:}\n{1:}\n{2:}\n{3:}\".format(sys.version, _md5, hl._hashlib, ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION))"
> 3.5.2 (default, Oct  8 2019, 13:06:37)
> [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
> <module '_md5' (built-in)>
> <module '_hashlib' from '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_hashlib.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'>
> OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
> [064bit-prompt]>
> [064bit-prompt]> ldd /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_hashlib.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
>         linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffa7d0b000)
>         libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f50d9e4d000)
>         libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f50d9a83000)
>         libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f50d963e000)
>         /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f50da271000)
>         libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f50d943a000)
> [064bit-prompt]>
> [064bit-prompt]> openssl version -a
> OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
> built on: reproducible build, date unspecified
> platform: debian-amd64
> options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(idx)
> compiler: cc -I. -I.. -I../include  -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -DMD32_REG_T=int -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM
> OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
> [064bit-prompt]>
> [064bit-prompt]> python3 -c "import _md5, hashlib as hl;print(_md5.md5(b\"A\").hexdigest(), hl.md5(b\"A\").hexdigest())"
> 7fc56270e7a70fa81a5935b72eacbe29 7fc56270e7a70fa81a5935b72eacbe29
> ```

According to [[Python 3.Docs]: hashlib.algorithms_guaranteed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.algorithms_guaranteed):

> A set containing the names of the hash algorithms guaranteed to be supported by this module on all platforms. Note that ‘md5’ is in this list despite some upstream vendors offering an odd “FIPS compliant” Python build that excludes it.

Below it's an example of **a custom *Python 2.7* installation** (that I built quite a while ago, worth mentioning that it dynamically links to *OpenSSL* *.dll*s):

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059955854]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> "F:\Install\pc064\HPE\OPSWpython\2.7.10__00\python.exe" -c "import sys, ssl;print(\"{0:}\n{1:}\".format(sys.version, ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION))"
> 2.7.10 (default, Mar  8 2016, 15:02:46) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]
> OpenSSL 1.0.2j-fips  26 Sep 2016
>
> [prompt]> "F:\Install\pc064\HPE\OPSWpython\2.7.10__00\python.exe" -c "import hashlib as hl;print(hl.md5(\"A\").hexdigest())"
> 7fc56270e7a70fa81a5935b72eacbe29
>
> [prompt]> "F:\Install\pc064\HPE\OPSWpython\2.7.10__00\python.exe" -c "import ssl;ssl.FIPS_mode_set(True);import hashlib as hl;print(hl.md5(\"A\").hexdigest())"
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
> ValueError: error:060A80A3:digital envelope routines:FIPS_DIGESTINIT:disabled for fips
> ```

As for the speed question I can only speculate:

- *Python* implementation was (obviously) written specifically for *Python*, meaning it is "more optimized" (yes, this is grammatically incorrect) for *Python* than a generic version, and also resides in *python*.so* (or the *python* executable itself)
- *OpenSSL* implementation resides in *libcrypto*.so*, and it's being accessed by the wrapper *_hashlib.so*, which does the back and forth conversions between *Python* types (*PyObject**) and the *OpenSSL* ones (*EVP_MD_CTX**)

Considering the above, it would make sense that the former is (slightly) faster (at least for small messages, where the overhead (function call and other *Python* underlying operations) takes a significant percentage of the total time compared to the hashing itself). There are also other factors to be considered (e.g. whether *OpenSSL* assembler speedups were used).

---

#### Update *#0*

Below are some benchmarks of my own.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import timeit
from hashlib import md5 as md5_openssl
from _md5 import md5 as md5_builtin


MD5S = (
    md5_openssl,
    md5_builtin,
)


def main(*argv):
    base_text = b"A"
    number = 1000000
    print("timeit attempts number: {:d}".format(number))
    #x = []
    #y = {}
    for count in range(0, 16):
        factor = 2 ** count
        text = base_text * factor
        globals_dict = {"text": text}
        #x.append(factor)
        print("\nUsing a {:8d} (2 ** {:2d}) bytes message".format(len(text), count))
        for func in MD5S:
            globals_dict["md5"] = func
            t = timeit.timeit(stmt="md5(text)", globals=globals_dict, number=number)
            print("    {:12s} took: {:11.6f} seconds".format(func.__name__, t))
            #y.setdefault(func.__name__, []).append(t)
    #print(x, y)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

- *Win 10 pc064* (running on a *Dell Precision 5510* laptop):

  > ```bat
  > [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
  > Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
  >
  > timeit attempts number: 1000000
  >
  > Using a        1 (2 **  0) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    0.449134 seconds
  >     md5          took:    0.120021 seconds
  >
  > Using a        2 (2 **  1) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    0.460399 seconds
  >     md5          took:    0.118555 seconds
  >
  > Using a        4 (2 **  2) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    0.451850 seconds
  >     md5          took:    0.121166 seconds
  >
  > Using a        8 (2 **  3) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    0.438398 seconds
  >     md5          took:    0.118127 seconds
  >
  > Using a       16 (2 **  4) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    0.454653 seconds
  >     md5          took:    0.122818 seconds
  >
  > Using a       32 (2 **  5) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    0.450776 seconds
  >     md5          took:    0.118594 seconds
  >
  > Using a       64 (2 **  6) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    0.555761 seconds
  >     md5          took:    0.278812 seconds
  >
  > Using a      128 (2 **  7) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    0.681296 seconds
  >     md5          took:    0.455921 seconds
  >
  > Using a      256 (2 **  8) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    0.895952 seconds
  >     md5          took:    0.807457 seconds
  >
  > Using a      512 (2 **  9) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    1.401584 seconds
  >     md5          took:    1.499279 seconds
  >
  > Using a     1024 (2 ** 10) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    2.360966 seconds
  >     md5          took:    2.878650 seconds
  >
  > Using a     2048 (2 ** 11) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    4.383245 seconds
  >     md5          took:    5.655477 seconds
  >
  > Using a     4096 (2 ** 12) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    8.264774 seconds
  >     md5          took:   10.920909 seconds
  >
  > Using a     8192 (2 ** 13) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:   15.521947 seconds
  >     md5          took:   21.895179 seconds
  >
  > Using a    16384 (2 ** 14) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:   29.947287 seconds
  >     md5          took:   43.198639 seconds
  >
  > Using a    32768 (2 ** 15) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:   59.123447 seconds
  >     md5          took:   86.453821 seconds
  >
  > Done.
  > ```
- *Ubuntu 16 pc064* (*VM* running in *VirtualBox* on the above machine):

  > ```
  > [064bit-prompt]> python3 ./code00.py
  > Python 3.5.2 (default, Oct  8 2019, 13:06:37) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] 64bit on linux
  >
  > timeit attempts number: 1000000
  >
  > Using a        1 (2 **  0) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    0.246166 seconds
  >     md5          took:    0.130589 seconds
  >
  > Using a        2 (2 **  1) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    0.251019 seconds
  >     md5          took:    0.127750 seconds
  >
  > Using a        4 (2 **  2) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    0.257018 seconds
  >     md5          took:    0.123116 seconds
  >
  > Using a        8 (2 **  3) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    0.245399 seconds
  >     md5          took:    0.128267 seconds
  >
  > Using a       16 (2 **  4) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    0.251832 seconds
  >     md5          took:    0.136373 seconds
  >
  > Using a       32 (2 **  5) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    0.248410 seconds
  >     md5          took:    0.140708 seconds
  >
  > Using a       64 (2 **  6) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    0.361016 seconds
  >     md5          took:    0.267021 seconds
  >
  > Using a      128 (2 **  7) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    0.478735 seconds
  >     md5          took:    0.413986 seconds
  >
  > Using a      256 (2 **  8) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    0.707602 seconds
  >     md5          took:    0.695042 seconds
  >
  > Using a      512 (2 **  9) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    1.216832 seconds
  >     md5          took:    1.268570 seconds
  >
  > Using a     1024 (2 ** 10) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    2.122014 seconds
  >     md5          took:    2.429623 seconds
  >
  > Using a     2048 (2 ** 11) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    4.158188 seconds
  >     md5          took:    4.847686 seconds
  >
  > Using a     4096 (2 ** 12) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    7.839173 seconds
  >     md5          took:    9.242224 seconds
  >
  > Using a     8192 (2 ** 13) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:   15.282232 seconds
  >     md5          took:   18.368874 seconds
  >
  > Using a    16384 (2 ** 14) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:   30.681912 seconds
  >     md5          took:   36.755073 seconds
  >
  > Using a    32768 (2 ** 15) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:   60.230543 seconds
  >     md5          took:   73.237356 seconds
  >
  > Done.
  > ```
- *Ubuntu 22 pc064* (dual-boot on the same machine):

  > ```
  > [064bit prompt]> python ./code00.py 
  > Python 3.10.12 (main, Jun 11 2023, 05:26:28) [GCC 11.4.0] 064bit on linux
  >
  > timeit attempts number: 1000000
  >
  > Using a        1 (2 **  0) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    0.258825 seconds
  >     md5          took:    0.092418 seconds
  >
  > Using a        2 (2 **  1) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    0.265123 seconds
  >     md5          took:    0.095969 seconds
  >
  > Using a        4 (2 **  2) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    0.273572 seconds
  >     md5          took:    0.098485 seconds
  >
  > Using a        8 (2 **  3) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    0.267524 seconds
  >     md5          took:    0.102606 seconds
  >
  > Using a       16 (2 **  4) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    0.295750 seconds
  >     md5          took:    0.102688 seconds
  >
  > Using a       32 (2 **  5) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    0.266704 seconds
  >     md5          took:    0.095375 seconds
  >
  > Using a       64 (2 **  6) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    0.350251 seconds
  >     md5          took:    0.209725 seconds
  >
  > Using a      128 (2 **  7) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    0.559193 seconds
  >     md5          took:    0.362671 seconds
  >
  > Using a      256 (2 **  8) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    0.685720 seconds
  >     md5          took:    0.589242 seconds
  >
  > Using a      512 (2 **  9) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    1.100991 seconds
  >     md5          took:    1.081601 seconds
  >
  > Using a     1024 (2 ** 10) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    2.069975 seconds
  >     md5          took:    2.176450 seconds
  >
  > Using a     2048 (2 ** 11) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    3.742486 seconds
  >     md5          took:    4.197531 seconds
  >
  > Using a     4096 (2 ** 12) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:    7.186287 seconds
  >     md5          took:    8.270421 seconds
  >
  > Using a     8192 (2 ** 13) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:   13.889762 seconds
  >     md5          took:   16.225811 seconds
  >
  > Using a    16384 (2 ** 14) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:   27.422105 seconds
  >     md5          took:   32.898019 seconds
  >
  > Using a    32768 (2 ** 15) bytes message
  >     openssl_md5  took:   54.010482 seconds
  >     md5          took:   64.579159 seconds
  >
  > Done.
  > ```

The result seem to be quite different than yours. In my case:

- Starting somewhere in [~*512B* .. ~*1KiB*] sized messages, *OpenSSL* implementation seems to perform better than builtin one
- I know that there are too few results to claim a pattern, but it seems that both implementations seem to be linearly proportional (in terms of time) with message size (but the builtin slope seems to be a bit steeper - meaning it will perform worse on the long run)

As a conclusion, if all your messages are small, and the builtin implementation works best for you, then use it.

---

#### Update *#1*

Graphical representation (I had to reduce the *timeit* iterations number by an order of magnitude, as it would take much too long for large messages):

[image: Img0]

and zooming on the area where the 2 graphs intersect:

[image: Img1]

Comment: Thank you for those benchmarks, could you add a line graph for them? Will be much easier to visualize the trend.

Answer (score 3):

My theory from looking around on bugs.python.org and reading the cpython git commit history:

cpython switched to openssl md5 in 2005 because it was faster than the built-in implementation. They added a new built-in implementation in 2007 that is faster than openssl but never switched back.  Both of these changes were done by Gregory P. Smith.

Here's my evidence.

- In 2005, Greg created [the bpo issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue1121611) "sha and md5 modules should use OpenSSL when possible". This change made in [this commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/f21a5f773964d34c7b6deb7e3d753fae2b9c70e2).
- In 2007, Greg added the new, fast md5 module in [this commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/2f21eb3a153ee09e333300a837be86a37cd22d28).
- The `_md5` implementation appears to be essentially the same in Python 3.8 (I'm looking at commit ea316fd21527)

I think the cpython maintainers would probably be open to switching back to `_md5` when it is available, since it's no longer true that the openssl implementation is faster (and may have been untrue for the last 13 years).

Comment: It looks as though the openssl implementation is actually performing better for messages more likely to be used in practice (i.e. files, order of kilobytes or larger).  See [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60263898/674039) about that.

Answer (score 2):

It is common for Python public modules to delegate methods to a hidden module.

For example, the full code of the `collections.abc` module is:

```
from _collections_abc import *
from _collections_abc import __all__
```

[The functions of `hashlib` are dynamically created](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/hashlib.py#L247):

```
for __func_name in __always_supported:
    # try them all, some may not work due to the OpenSSL
    # version not supporting that algorithm.
    try:
        globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
```

[The definition of `always_supported` is](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/hashlib.py#L58):

```
__always_supported = ('md5', 'sha1', 'sha224', 'sha256', 'sha384', 'sha512',
                      'blake2b', 'blake2s',
                      'sha3_224', 'sha3_256', 'sha3_384', 'sha3_512',
                      'shake_128', 'shake_256')
```

[And `get_hash`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/hashlib.py#L166) either `__get_openssl_constructor` or `__get_builtin_constructor`:

```
try:
    import _hashlib
    new = __hash_new
    __get_hash = __get_openssl_constructor
    algorithms_available = algorithms_available.union(
            _hashlib.openssl_md_meth_names)
except ImportError:
    new = __py_new
    __get_hash = __get_builtin_constructor
```

[`__get_builtin_constructor` is a fallback for the (again) hidden `_hashlib` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/hashlib.py#L123):

```
def __get_openssl_constructor(name):
    if name in __block_openssl_constructor:
        # Prefer our blake2 and sha3 implementation.
        return __get_builtin_constructor(name)
    try:
        f = getattr(_hashlib, 'openssl_' + name)
        # Allow the C module to raise ValueError.  The function will be
        # defined but the hash not actually available thanks to OpenSSL.
        f()
        # Use the C function directly (very fast)
        return f
    except (AttributeError, ValueError):
        return __get_builtin_constructor(name)
```

Above in the [`hashlib` code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/hashlib.py#L79), you have this:

```
def __get_builtin_constructor(name):
    cache = __builtin_constructor_cache
    ...
    elif name in {'MD5', 'md5'}:
        import _md5
        cache['MD5'] = cache['md5'] = _md5.md5
```

But `md5` is not in `__block_openssl_constructor`, hence the `_hashlib/openssl` version is preferred to the `_md5/builtin` version:

Confirmation in the REPL:

```
>>> hashlib.md5
<built-in function openssl_md5>
>>> _md5.md5
<built-in function md5>
```

Those functions are different implementations of the MD5 algorithm and the `openssl_md5` makes a call to a dynamic system library. That's why you have some performance changes. The first version is defined in https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_hashopenssl.c and the other in https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/md5module.c, if you want to check the differences.

Then why is the `_md5.md5` function defined but never used? I guess the idea is to ensure that some algorithms are always available, even if `openssl` is absent:

> Constructors for hash algorithms that are always present in this module are sha1(), sha224(), sha256(), sha384(), sha512(), blake2b(), and blake2s(). (https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html)

Comment: Hi jferard, 90% of the answer is about the low-level details of how `hashlib.md5` will get bound to either a built-in md5 implementation or an openssl_md5 implementation. But the mechanics of how those imports/fallbacks are implemented are boring details (I can read it in the source too). For this bounty I'm more interested in an answer that explains how openssl and built-in md5 implementation differ, and why the apparently faster built-in version is not chosen as default. Was the openssl implementation superior in some way? Why?

Comment: Can you add profiling evidence that the performance difference is due to overhead from a call to a dynamic system library?